# Why does this C++ program doesn't work for 17 13 3 5

Tags: c++, c, max

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;


int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
         return( max((a,b),max(c,d)));
    }

int main()


{
        int a, b, c, d;
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
        int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
        printf("%d", ans);

        return 0;
    }
```

I ran this code on hackerRank. This code is doing fine for other testcases
except for:
17 13 3 15

for which it outputs : 15

I also tried to run the max(a,b) for 17 13
for which it righteously outputs 17.

Please Help!

Comment: What does `(a, b)` evaluate to?

Comment: Side note: std::max({a, b, c, d}); will do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone.
It has been silly of me, not to notice this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten to put `max` here

```
return(max((a,b),max(c,d)));
```

It should be `return( max(max(a,b),max(c,d)));`

By the way, you really don't need the parentheses after `return` as they're just making the code heavier and result in too many parentheses.

Comment: Thanks :)

btw can you help me with this which one's a better approach to solve this problem:

using max() ;
using a fifth variable & comparing it ; 

or using comparison without the fifth variable? or any other (in terms of time & space complexity)?

Comment: @dj1, to my mind, your program's OK. As it was suggested in comments, you can use `std::max` to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
return( max((a,b),max(c,d)));
```

basically evaluates to

```
return( max(b,max(c,d)));
```

probably you are looking for

```
return  max( max(a,b), max(c,d) );
```

Comment: Thanks :) btw can you help me with this which one's a better approach to solve this problem: using max() ; using a fifth variable & comparing it ; or using comparison without the fifth variable? or any other (in terms of time & space complexity)?